# Strings of consecutive integers divisible by 1, 2, 3, ..., N

Tags: nt.number-theory

For each *n*, let $a_n$ be the least integer, greater than *n*, such that the numbers $a_n$, $a_n$+ 1, $a_n$+ 2, ..., $a_n$+ (*n* – 1) are divisible, in some order, by 1, 2, 3, ..., *n*. For example $a_{12}$ = 110.

What are the best estimates known for  $a_n$?

Comment: There is no such integer if $n>1$ because $a$ and $a+1$ are always relatively prime.

Comment: @JohannesHahn, note that the question is only asking for $n$ different numbers to each be divisible by one of $n$ different values.

Comment: Why is it not $a_n=1$ for all $n$?

Comment: I still do not understand. Starting from $a_n=1$ we obtain $1, 2, \ldots,n$, that are divisible (in some order, i.e. the trivial one) by $1, 2, \ldots,n$. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe the OP wants a bound for the minimal solution *greater than $1$*?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: You are right, I will clarify that.

Comment: are you sure that $a_{12}=110$? What is the corresponding permutation in $S_{12}$?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: 10,3,8,1,6,5,4,9,2,7,12,11

Comment: ok. How did you check that this is the minimum solution >1? By brute force?

Comment: OK, why not $a_n = 2$?  $2,3,4,\ldots, n, n+1$ are divisible by $2,3,4,\ldots, n, 1$ in that order.

Comment: Maybe you want $a_n > n$?  Then see [OEIS sequence A138588](https://oeis.org/A138588).

Comment: @RobertIsrael Right again. I have now amended the question accordingly. Interesting to note, examining the relevant OEIS item, that the sequence is not strictly increasing.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what is the best estimate for $a_n$. However, one can easily found an upper bound noticing that an integer $x$ satisfying your condition can be found by solving a system of congruences
$$x +i \equiv 0  \; \; \mathrm{mod}\, (i+1), \quad i=0, \ldots, n-1.$$

A solution is given by $x=1$, so all solutions are of the form $1+kN(n)$, where $k$ is an integer and $N(n)=lcm(1, \ldots, n)$. It follows that $$a_n \leq 1+N(n).$$

A (very time-consuming) algorithm finding $a_n$ is the following. Given a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$, denote by $x_{\sigma}$ the least solution $> n$ of the system of linear congruences $$x +i \equiv 0  \; \; \mathrm{mod}\, (\sigma(i+1)), \quad i=0, \ldots, n-1.$$

Then $$a_n = \min_{\sigma \in S_n} x_{\sigma}.$$

Comment: One wonders whether your maximum value is attained infinitely often. Unlikely, I would conjecture.

Comment: Is it attained at least once for $n \geq 3$?

Comment: Except the conditions are a lot more strict. It is unclear that all permutations of primes will serve, and you only need to check half of them. (Also, for n large enough N(n)/2 is a strict upper bound.) Gerhard "Has Looked At This Before" Paseman, 2019.03.29.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect (and would appreciate verification by someone else) that a more time efficient alternative to Francesco Polizzi's suggestion is the following: generate all such sequences less than $N(n)$, and then use them to generate sequences for n+1. Of course, if we have such an interval starting at $a$, then there is another ending at $N(n)-a$

At the very least, one needs a sequence of numbers of length about $n/2$ (and usually longer) adjacent to a multiple of $n+1$ and this sequence forms a consecutive interval of integers none of which are coprime to $ N(n)$. Since most such sequences are of length log n, there should be relatively few of this length (although more than the number of permutations of $\pi(n)$).  I do not have numerics at hand, but my gut feeling is that the number of such intervals should be way less than $n!$. A recent preprint on Arxiv by Mario Ziller distantly relates to this problem; his (with John Morack) published algorithms should be adaptable to this problem.

**Edit 2019.04.16:**

It is taking me longer than usual to program. I will describe an algorithm which should shed light on this problem, and which may lead to a proof that an upper bound on the desired number is (for $n \gt 3$) much smaller than $N(n)$, and likely smaller (for $n \gt 10$) than $P(n)/2,$ the product of the odd primes smaller than $n$.

As noted elsewhere, an obstruction to $I=[m+1,m+n]$ having a bijection $d()$ to $[1,n]$ so that for each integer $d(l)$ in the range one has $d(l)$ divides $l$ is that there are two primes (with sizes) bigger than $n$ in the domain interval. More generally, there are at least two obstructions: that $I$ contains two numbers coprime to $N(n)$, and that a special multiple occurs in the middle of $I$, for example $m + 2 \lt Kn(n-1) \lt m+n-1$. The special multiple says that there is only one place in $I$ for multiples of two numbers less than $n$. A more general obstruction is that in $I$ the multiples of $j$ numbers less than $n$ occupy together less than $j$ spots, which looks a lot like the first obstruction as $j$ gets large.

I am still writing code for the second obstruction. For the first obstruction, it is easy to write code to determine the sequence of units in the ring of integers mod $P(n)$, and not much harder to determine mod $P(n)$ the count of possible values which avoid the first obstruction. For example, for $n=6$, one looks at a sequence of differences 6 4 2 4 2 4 6 2 and concludes that for $n=6$ and $P(6)=2*3*5=30$ one must have modulo $30$ that $m+1$ must be in $[0,5] \cup [20,25]$. This example does not show the second obstruction clearly, but if we took $n=5$, then $m=17$ mod $60$ would be ruled out by a large multiple of $20=5*4$ occurring in the middle of $I$.

Initial runs of the code modelling the first obstruction suggest that when $n$ is prime less than $ 1/(n\log n)$ of the numbers in $[0,P(n))$ avoid the obstruction and are candidates for $m$, and when $n$ is not prime the number drops from $1/(n \log n)$ to something like $1/n^2$.  I expect the second obstruction to remove about $1/n$ of these candidates, and hope to post numbers later.  I invite others to write and share code for some modification of the first and second obstructions to come up with the density of $m$ satisfying Bernardo's divisibility condition.

**End Edit 2019.04.16.**

Gerhard "More General Than Jacobsthal's Function" Paseman, 2019.03.29.

Comment: Here is an approach which is worthy of study, even if it is (potentially) computationally inefficient, as it may provide a good upper bound to the number of such intervals. Note that any such interval cannot contain a pair of primes larger than n. Also, it cannot contain two such numbers of the form kp, kq, with p and q prime larger than n and k a number less than n.  This suggests using the distribution of primes to constrain rapidly the number and location of several such intervals.  Gerhard "Can Find Where It Isn't" Paseman, 2019.03.29.

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n=a \gt n,$ then there can only be one prime
among $a,a+1,\cdots, a+n-1.$ So the well studied topic of gaps between primes could provide upper bounds and might be the  major factor.

Here are the gaps between the first few primes

$ 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6, 4, 2, 4, 6, 6$

$, 2, 6, 4, 2, 6, 4, 6, 8$

$4 , 2, 4, 2, 4, 14, 4,$

The record gaps indicated are are $14=127-113$ , and $8=97-89$

We are here most interested in the [gap between the $k$th and $k+2$nd  prime](https://oeis.org/A031131)s

$3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 10, 8, 8, 10, 6, 6, 10, 12,$

$8, 8, 10, 6, 8, 10, 10, 14$

$ 6, 6, 6, 6, 18, 18$

The entries at least $13$ indicate the intervals that might perhaps contain $a_{12}$

The $14$ seems like a tight fit. We need to use either $84$ or $96$ (which will be the multiple of $12$) along with $85\cdots 95.$ But this fails as $88$ is the only available multiple of $8$ and also of $11.$ So in fact $a_{11}$ has to be further out.

The $18$’s show more promise : either part of

$110,111,112,\mathbf{113},\cdots ,126$ or part of

$114,\cdots ,\mathbf{127},128,129,130.$ The multiple of $11$ must be $110$ or $121$ and, since $110$ works, we are done.

It turns out that $a_{10}=a_{11}=a_{12}=110.$

It is possible to have $a_{i+1} \lt a_i.$

Comment: Even simpler, given n and m the product of primes at most n, one can't have two numbers coprime to m in the same interval of length n. I am using this to compute the density of possible starting points of intervals, which may give a clue as to an upper bound for the first one greater than n.  Gerhard "But First, A Musical Interlude..." Paseman, 2019.03.29.